# Job scheduling c++ simulation, need advice/suggestion

Tags: c++, algorithm, simulation, job-scheduling

I have started creating a c++ program to simulate job scheduling algorithms like FiFo and others. I am far from done but my main problem now is how to create the flow of time in my program.

This is my main code so far:

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  Time1 = clock();
  //this is the alogrithm to generate poisson arrival sequence
  do{   
    k = k + 1;
    // Generate a random number between 0 and 1
    // return a uniform number in [0,1].
    double u = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;   
    p = p * u;
  }while (p > L);
  A[i] = k-1;   

  Time2 = clock();  
  DT = Time2 -Time1;
  TotalTime=TotalTime + DT;
  cout << "  Total time  " << TotalTime 
       << "  table :" << A[i] 
       << "  Arrival Time  "            
       << TotalTime <<endl ;
```

My main problem is :
my time measuring units with clock are that the time units that are outputted from clock() function are "weird" numbers. Should I use another function?

Results from 10 iteration

```
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :28  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :29  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :30  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :31  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :32  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :33  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :34  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :35  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
  Total time  6.19522e+032  table :36  Arrival Time  6.19522e+032
```

**PS**: I can provide the rest of the code if you want to run it in your machine.

Comment: what is your Time1 and Time2's type?

Comment: floats. acutally every variable is float at the moment cause i started  yesterday and didnt have time to decide

Comment: show what the other variables `p, L, A` etc. are.

Comment: they are all floats , cause i dont know the function clock good so i though put them all as floats for now ******
int i;
 float l=25;
 float L=exp(-l);
 float k=0;
 float p=1;
float A[1000];
float Time1;
float Time2;
float TotalTime;
float DT;

Comment: Looks to me like you're using the wrong data type. `clock()` returns `clock_t`. Making them all float type seems suspect. The arithmetic will promote float to double and then convert back to float again in the loop. Doing this multiple times in the loop will have precision loss.

Comment: i tried using double and long double but got again very big numbers :S

Comment: Did you initialize TotalTime to zero?

Comment: now they are all zeros which is something , but now i have to check if this system works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Job scheduling would be much, much easier to do as a "discrete-event" simulation.  Check out this [tutorial paper](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc06papers/001.pdf) to see how such models can be constructed.  The framework in the paper is in Java (and has also been implemented in Ruby), but would be straight-up to port to C++.

Answer (score 0):

So the first point is that clock() returns a clock_t variable so, although I don't think it will really make much of a different, make Time1 and Time2 be of type clock_t. As for the main question and from the comments, looks like you just forgot to initialize TotalTime to zero, which would explain the huge numbers.

If the output is all zero then yes the loop probably is running very quickly but you can also increase the number of decimal places you output by using setprecision. Run the following code to see the difference, cout.setprecision(int value) will determine how many decimal places to show.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double d = 1.0/3.0;

    std::cout.precision(15);

    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    std::cout.precision(3);

    std::cout << d;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should i include this in my code like a separate class? i made all time variables clock_t type

Comment: i got it in my code inside the do while. seems the clock variables are integers atm counting from 0 to 1

Comment: Ah yes clock_t appears to be, at least on my machine, an int. If you loop runs too quickly it will just give you a zero as the difference in clock() values.

Comment: i tried adding this command **(clock()>Time1)** before Time2 = clock(); to make it move one step at a time but now i am not getting any results